# Ajax form sent success but no email

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an **AJAX** form which is saying its successful but still not receiving any emails from this, very annoying.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

/*
    Code by David McKeown
    www.craftedbydavid.com
*/

jQuery(document).ready(function () { // wait until the document is ready
    jQuery('#send').click(function(){ // when the button is clicked the code executes
        jQuery('.error').fadeOut('slow'); // reset the error messages (hides them)

        var error = false; // we will set this true if the form isn't valid

        var name = jQuery('input#name').val(); // get the value of the input field
        if(name == "" || name == " ") {
            jQuery('#err-name').fadeIn('slow'); // show the error message
            error = true; // change the error state to true
        }

        var phone = jQuery('input#phone').val(); // get the value of the input field
        if(phone == "" || phone == " ") {
            jQuery('#err-phone').fadeIn('slow'); // show the error message
            error = true; // change the error state to true
        }

        var email_compare = /^([a-z0-9_.-]+)@([da-z.-]+).([a-z.]{2,6})$/; // Syntax to compare against input
        var email = jQuery('input#email').val(); // get the value of the input field
        if (email == "" || email == " ") { // check if the field is empty
            jQuery('#err-email').fadeIn('slow'); // error - empty
            error = true;

        }else if (!email_compare.test(email)) { // if it's not empty check the format against our email_compare variable
            jQuery('#err-emailvld').fadeIn('slow'); // error - not right format
            error = true;
        }

        if(error == true) {
            jQuery('#err-form').slideDown('slow');
            return false;
        }

        var data_string = jQuery('#ajax-form').serialize(); // Collect data from form
        //alert(data_string);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: jQuery('#ajax-form').attr('action'),
            data: data_string,
            timeout: 6000,
            error: function(request,error) {
                if (error == "timeout") {
                    jQuery('#err-timedout').slideDown('slow');
                }
                else {
                    jQuery('#err-state').slideDown('slow');
                    jQuery("#err-state").html('An error occurred: ' + error + '');
                }
            },
            success: function() {
                jQuery('#ajax-form').slideUp('slow');
                jQuery('#ajaxsuccess').slideDown('slow');
            }
        });

        return false; // stops user browser being directed to the php file
    }); // end click function
});

</script>
```

HTML FORM >>>>>>>>>>>>>>

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<form name="ajax-form" id="ajax-form" action="mail-it.php" method="post">
    <p>
      <label for="name">Name: * 
        <span class="error" id="err-name">please enter name</span>
        <br />
      </label>

      <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br /><br />

          <label for="phone">Contact Number: * 
        <span class="error" id="err-phone">please enter phone number</span>
        <br />
      </label>

      <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text" />

      <label for="email">
        <br />
        E-Mail: * 
        <span class="error" id="err-email">please enter e-mail</span>
        <span class="error" id="err-emailvld">e-mail is not a valid format</span><br />
      </label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

    <p>


      <label for="message">Message:</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>

    <div class="myButton"><INPUT type="submit" name="" value="" id="send"></div>


<div class="mainerror">
<div class="error" id="err-form">There was a problem validating the form please check!</div>
    <div class="error" id="err-timedout">The connection to the server timed out!</div>
    <div class="error" id="err-state"></div></div>
</form>
<div id="ajaxsuccess"><h2>Successfully sent!!</h2></div>
```

MAIL PHP SEND MAIL-IT.PHP

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

<?php



/* Code by David McKeown - craftedbydavid.com */

/* Editable entries are bellow */



$send_to = "MYEMAIL@MYDOMAIN.co.uk";

$send_subject = "Website Enquiry ";







/*Be careful when editing below this line */



$f_name = cleanupentries($_POST["name"]);

$f_phone = cleanupentries($_POST["phone"]);

$f_email = cleanupentries($_POST["email"]);

$f_message = cleanupentries($_POST["message"]);

$from_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$from_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];



function cleanupentries($entry) {

    $entry = trim($entry);

    $entry = stripslashes($entry);

    $entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);



    return $entry;

}



$message = "This email was submitted on " . date('m-d-Y') . 

"\n\nName: " . $f_name .

"\n\nPhone: " . $f_phone . 

"\n\nE-Mail: " . $f_email . 

"\n\nMessage: \n" . $f_message . 

"\n\n\nTechnical Details:\n" . $from_ip . "\n" . $from_browser;



$send_subject .= " - {$f_name}";



$headers = "From: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .

    "Reply-To: " . $f_email . "\r\n" .

    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();



if (!$f_email) {

    echo "no email";

    exit;

}else if (!$f_name){

    echo "no name";

    exit;

}else if (!$f_phone){

    echo "no phone";

    exit;

}else{

    if (filter_var($f_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);

        echo "true";

    }else{

        echo "invalid email";

        exit;

    }

}



?>
```

The form does say success, but still not receiving the emails! any ideas?

Comment: Check your SMTP settings dude.

Comment: If the AJAX is successful then your problem is purely PHP related

Comment: May be a good idea to actually look at the response from the server, rather than just relying on the fact that it returns *something*.

Comment: Arvind Bhardwaj - Thanks - Correct, I have just figured out that one of our member of staff has gone over the threshold of mass mailing this morning so that particular domain cannot receive emails, tested to another domain email and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

As you have kept button type to be submit it is performing in the default way.

So on the submit event, just cancel the form submission and run your AJAX code.

```
$('#ajax-form').bind('submit',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); //Will prevent the submit...
  //Add your code here
});
```

Comment: They're already preventing the click on the submit button using `return false`, so the `submit` event wouldn't be fired anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check your error log, this will give you more information about what is really happening.

Comment: Arvind Bhardwaj - Thanks - Correct, I have just figured out that one of our member of staff has gone over the threshold of mass mailing this morning so that particular domain cannot receive emails, tested to another domain email and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Test your `mail-it.php` standalone. Comment out `jQuery('#send').click(function(){ ... }` part .Then in `mail-it.php` add following line in end to print last error.

```
print_r(error_get_last());    // php >= 5.2.0
```

Now try submitting the form.This should redirect to `mail-it.php` script upon submit and printing error array if any.Try to rectify if it throws some info.